# Engadget Like Featured Breaking Plugin

Tags: plugins

I am looking for a Engadget like **featured breaking** plugin. I have searched myself but did not found any relevant results. I would be very thankful for the help.

### EDIT:

Here is a visual image of how it should look like. 
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have an example of what you want?

Comment: @VincePettit: I have given a visual image now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a plugin that does this here:

http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/recent-posts

Called recent posts, you can add the widget and change the Title to 'Featured Breaking'

[image]